# Aldol Condensation Product selection

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aldol-reaction

It is known that the enol form double bond tends to attack the electrophilic carbon centre in an aldol reaction. But what will be the majour product in this reaction.

The latter one may be enol attack but forming a 5 membered ring. The former apparently is more stable forming a six membered ring but the enol form is less stable having lower no. of hyperconjugating structures(since greater number of hyperconjugation structures directs to more stablity.) So, is the keto form actually involved in aldol in this case, contrary to general mechanism? Moreover what will be the majour product?[image]

Comment: In example 1 the alternative product is a 4-membered ring which is disfavoured because of ring strain. In example 2 the alternative is a 7-membered ring which is disfavoured relative to [5]. Remember that in each case you are getting the thermodynamic product as these reactions are reversible.

Comment: I think that stability of the 6 member ring will pull the reaction forward..